# Django superuser page not found

Tags: django

If I give superuser status to a user or create a new superuser, that user will not open their own profile page. Get the error page not found, at the same time opens the admin panel. All other functions on the site, such as login and commenting, he also performs without problems, but the user's own page does not open

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
> URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/6/ Raised
> by:   profiles.views.profiles

**views.py**:

```
def profiles(request, pk=0):
post_form = ArticleForm()
now_user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) # require user
posts = Article.objects.filter(author=now_user) # posts require users
profile = Profile.objects.get(id=pk) # users not require 
posts_other = profile.author.all() # posts not require users

# count comment for not request user
comm_post = get_object_or_404(Article, id=pk)
comm = comm_post.comments_post.all()
count_com = comm.count()

# count comment for request user
#------

if request.method == "POST":
    post_form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if post_form.is_valid():
        new_post = post_form.save(commit=False)
        now_user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        new_post.author = now_user
        new_post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/profile/{pk}')


context = {  'profile':profile, 
             'posts_other':posts_other,
             'post_form' : post_form,
             'posts' : posts,
             'count_com':count_com,
           
             }
return render(request, 'profiles/account.html', context)
```

**models.py**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    last_name  = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default = 'avatar.svg', upload_to = 'avatars/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='friends')
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}"


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

**template.html**:

```
      {% if profile.user == request.user %}
              <img src="{{user.profile.avatar.url}}" class="img-fluid" width="350px" />
                <a href="{% url 'change_avatar' profile.id %}"
                  class="btn btn-sm btn-succes card-body container "
                  type="submit"/>
                  Change avatar</a>
            <div class="card-body center">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{user.username}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                <p>registered {{user.profile.created|date:'Y-m-d'}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">about: {{user.profile.about}}</p>
              </p >
              <a  href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm "> Friends </a>
              <a href="{% url 'postman:inbox' %}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm "
                >messages</a>
            </div>
    
              <!--****************Profile  not request ******************-->
                        {% else %}
            <img src="{{profile.avatar.url}}" class="img-fluid" width="350px" />
    
            <div class="card-body center">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{profile.user}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                 <p>registered {{user.profile.created|date:'Y-m-d'}}</p>
                 <p class="card-text">about: {{user.profile.about}}</p>
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">add to friend</a>
              
              <a href="{% url 'postman:write' %}"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1">send a message</a>
               
            </div>
             {% endif %}
```

login.view

```
def login(request, id=0):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        try:
            remember = request.POST['remember_me']
            if remember:
                settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
        except:
            is_private = False
            settings.SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)

            return redirect('profile',  id = user.id)
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html')
```

Comment: Please share full error traceback.

Comment: sharred full error

Comment: Can you then add full code of your `def profiles()`?

Comment: why do you use pk=0 by default here def profiles(request, pk=0) ?

Comment: @MrHow, It seems you are using `raise Http404()` in your `profiles()`.

Comment: NKSM i added full def profile()

Comment: about pk=0, i have seen that in some examplase, and thought that good practice that dont get error when func dont find pk. Apparently this is bad practice.

Comment: @MrHow,  Use `try except block` instead `get_object_or_404`, if some object is not essential. And you can stay use `pk=0` or `pk=None` if argument is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mr How- First, you have a major flaw in your application as pointed out by other users in the comments. Passing default pk=0. Don't do this. The error you are receiving shows that the Profile doesn't exist with that id=6. If you think it exists then log the queryset inside the profiles view and show us.
Major flaws -

1. Using pk in your URLs. This is a bad practice. You can use a slug or some sort of UUID which is random. Don't use sequential id as other users will be able to change the id in the URL and fetch other user's profiles and start editing unless you have some logic to prevent that.
2. Next, what happens if a profile doesn't exist. If a user has created an account then he/she must have a profile. If a profile is missing then check your post_save()

I am adding some modifications to your models and views.

```
  class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True,db_index=True)
 ....................


 def ProfileDetailView(request,profile_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(profile_id=profile_id)
    context = {  'profile':profile, 
                ...}
    return render(request, 'profiles/account.html', context)



 url(r'^(profile/?P<profile_id>[0-9a-f-]+)/detail/$', login_required(views.ProfileDetailView),
        name='profile-detail'),
path('profile/<uuid:profile_id>/detail/', views.ProfileDetailView)
```

Comment: first thanks for your detailed answer, I added my observations to the account of the existence of the user. What you say is difficult for me, I'm new to django and not familiar with models.UUIDField, I will try to edit the code according to your example, but I suppose it uses the old django syntax in url?

Comment: how i convert this url for django.urls.path?

Comment: @MrHow- I have edited the code. Have a look

Comment: Thanks, but  how i use this code  (profile/<uuid:profile_id>/detail/') with redirect in my def?

Comment: @MrHow- Can you elaborate your question a bit ?

Comment: def ProfileDetailView(request, profile_id):
    ...
        return redirect(f'/profile/{pk}')
    ...    
    how to register a redirect taking into account the new conditions in the url and def

Comment: @MrHow- Your ProfileDetailView will render the html template that contains your profile  details. Why would you want to redirect? render should work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228805/discussion-between-mr-how-and-sdrj).

Comment: i get error OverflowError at /profile/c78c29e4-ed9c-4c7e-a0f8-4647fbec5dd4/detail/                  Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

Comment: @MrHow-   profile_id = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True,db_index=True,max_length=200) ....change it to this

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('c78c29e4ed9c4c7ea0f84647fbec5dd4',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P<profile_id>[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})/detail/$']

Comment: WHy you say " Passing default pk=0. Don't do this. " ? What kinda is problem?

Comment: Why would you pass default pk=0 at the first place? What purpose does it serve? @MrHow

Comment: (added a view to the question), in order to access the login page, I put a nude value.

Comment: @MrHow- Did you manage to resolve the error?

Comment: no, I went back to the sequential id, as there is no problem, the user profile is not private information, there are restrictions on making changes. But my main question is still not resolved, I cannot open the users page, the error page is not found

Comment: I found the problem was here (comm_post = get_object_or_404 (Article, id = pk)), if there was no article, a 404 error was generated